# Can't access Hadoop administration Jobtracker GUI

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to use Hadoop Administration Web Page GUI.

By Running `jps` command I get:

```
30297 SecondaryNameNode
31462 TaskTracker
31502 Jps
```

But when I try to load `http://hadoop:50030/jobtracker.jsp` or `localhost:50030` in my Firefix browser, it doesn't respond. But when I Run `sudo curl localhost:50030` command in the terminal I get this:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0;url=jobtracker.jsp"/>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hadoop Administration</title>
</head>    
<body>
<h1>Hadoop Administration</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="jobtracker.jsp">JobTracker</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why I can't access Hadoop administration Jobtracker GUI ?

(I use Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: Why hadoop:50030 in Firefox? Have you tried localhost:50030 in Firefox ?

Comment: yes actually I write localhost:50030. when I copied the URL it changed to hadoop !